# find roots in the complexes

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Find the roots of: $$ z^2 -3z +4iz = 1-5i $$

Rearranging the terms: $z^2 + z(4i-3) + 5i - 1 $

Solving by using the quadratic formula:

$$z_{1,2} = \frac{3-4i\pm \sqrt{(4i-3)^2 -4(5i-1)}}{2}$$

If I simplify the root, I get something relatively ugly. 
Is that what I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. You have $$ \begin {align*} \sqrt {(4i-3)^2 - 4(5i-1)} &= \sqrt {-16 + 9 - 24i - 20i + 4} \\&= \sqrt {-3 - 44i}. \end {align*} $$From here, you can use DeMoivre's theorem and it is [indeed ugly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28-3-44i%29). Nothing you can do if that's the question.

Comment: @AlonAlon You're welcome!